# Delphi teechart locking form on update

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, teechart

I have a tdbchart running in my app, that updates every 5 seconds, however when it updates it locks up my form so I cant use it while its updating.

Is there any way I can stop the form from locking up when the updates occurs?

Its highly frustrating if the user cant use the form every 5seconds.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use BeginUpdate already?    chart.Series[x].BeginUpdate;
   Dataset.Requery;
   chart.Series[x].EndUpdate;

Comment: How much data do you display in the chart? Must be a lot, because normally you do not even recognize these updates.

Comment: @bummi No I don't use that I use the auto refresh function on the teechart type. Smasher; not a lot but it pulls through my network from a view in MSSQL, my graphs do no physical calculations themselves.

Comment: Retrieve your data inside a background thread and pass them synchronized to the chart

Comment: If you have a lot of data in your chart, it takes a while to draw it. And if you are redrawing the chart each 5 seconds, it could be the reason of the problem. Try disabling AutoRepaint and repainting manually when desired.

Comment: @SirRufo thank you for your answer it makes more sense that way

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the `DBChart1.OnProcessRecord` event calling `Application.ProcessMessages` to make the refresh more responsive.